# Minimum number of operations to make A and B equal simultaneously

Tags: algorithm

Given two non-negative integers A and B, find the minimum number of operations to make them equal simultaneously. In one operation, you can:

- either change A to 2*A
- or change B to 2*B
- or change both A and B to A-1, B-1

For example: A = 7, B = 25

Sequence of operations would be:

1. 6 24
2. 12 24
3. 24 24

We cannot make them equal in less than 3 operations

I was asked this coding question in a test a week ago. Cannot think of a solution, it is stuck in my head.The input A and B were somewhat over 10^12 so it is clear that I cannot use a loop else it will exceed time limit.

Comment: Cannot use a loop, it probably has some formula like logic

Comment: You do not have to use a loop. If those are 32 bit numbers, just do those steps 32 times in a row. Are you allowed to compare the numbers? Do you have knowledge of the numbers or should the operations work with any number?

Comment: A and B input values are too big

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show a [mcve] please.

Comment: Any loop is forbidden including `while` or loops with template metaprogramming? Are `if` or jumps or recursive functions allowed? Is the focus on the minimum number of operations?

Comment: yes, minimum number of operations is the focus else using loop i can make it equal, the problem is how to make it minimum

Comment: It could be something like: put both numbers into binary representation. Decrease both until the representation of the larger one (the one with more digits) starts with the smaller one, or, if there is at least one digit `1` in the right part (the part which is longer than the smaller one) of the larger one, decrease, until the larger one starts with (smaller one - 1). Double the smaller one. Optionally decrease, double, optionally decrease and so on.

Comment: E.g. larger one: 1011001, smaller one 111. Decrease. 1011001/110. Double. 1011001/1100. Double. 1011001/11000. Decrease. 1011000/10111. Oops, decreasing would change the larger number. We have to consider beforehand, how often we would decrease. It could be 1 plus the number of zeros between the rightmost (LSB) 1 in the right part of the larger number.

Comment: Again: E.g. larger one: 1011001, smaller one 111. Decrease. 1011001/110. We have two zeros, so we would decrease three more times. After subtracting 3, the large number would be 1010110. Double. 1011001/1100. Decrease. 1011000/1011. Double. 1011000/10110. Double. 1011000/101100. Double. 1011000/1011000. We were finished with less decreasing.

Comment: I feel like this post just got closed and reposted?

Comment: @user438383 yes, i had put wrong title which i realized after reviewing the post when it was closed, hence deleted

Comment: @Sebastian no, this approach is giving wrong answer

Comment: Are the integers infinite precision, or do they wrap around modulo 2**N?

Comment: @pts wdym by infinite precision?

Comment: By infinite precision, I mean X+1 is never 0.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I added it coz i did not want people to explain logic in other languages

Answer (score 0):

A slow but working solution:

1. If they are equal, stop.
2. If one of them is 0, stop with failure (there is no solution if negative numbers are not allowed).
3. While both are larger than 1, decrease both.
4. Now the smaller is 1, the other is larger.
5. While the smaller has a shorter binary representation, double the smaller.
6. Continue at step 1.

In step 4, the maximum decreases. In step 5, the absolute difference decreases. Thus eventually the algorithm terminates.

Comment: This is not a working solution. A working solution would return the **minimum** number of operations needed to make the two numbers equal. We all know there is **some** sequence of operations that makes the two numbers equal. The objective is not to find one.

Comment: The very first sentence of my answer indicates that the algorith is slow, there is no ambiguity.

Comment: At least it proves there is a solution for every pair of numbers.

Comment: You are asked to find the minimal length of the sequence of operations. You are finding something else entirely (not a length of anything, and not a minimal anything). How fast or slow you are doing it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

This should give the optimal solution. We have to compare a few different ways and take the best solution.

1. One working solution is to double the smaller number as many times as it stays below the larger number (can be zero times). Then calculate the difference between the double of the (possibly multiple times) doubled smaller number and the larger number. And decrease the numbers as many times. Then double the smaller number one more time. [If the numbers are equal from the beginning, the solution is trivial instead.] This gives an upper bound of the steps.
2. Now try out the following optimizations:

2a) Choose a number n between 0 and up to the number of steps of the best solution so far.

2b) Choose one number as A and one number as B (two possibilities).

2c) Now count the applied steps of the following procedure.

3. Double A n times.
4. Calculate the smallest power of 2 (=m), with which `B * 2^m >= A`. m should be at least 1.
5. Calculate the difference of A with the product from step 4 in a mixed base (correct term?) system with each digit having a positional value of `2^(n+1)-1`, which is from the least significant right digit to the left: 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, ... From all possible representations the number must have the smallest crosssum, e.g. 100 for 7 is correct, 021 not. Sidenote: For the least checksum there will mostly be digits 0 and 1 and at most one digit 2, no other digits. There will never be a digit 1 right of a 2.)
6. Represent the number as m digits by filling the left positions with zero. If the number does not fit, go back to step 2 for another selection.
7. Take the most significant not processed digit from step 6 and do as many decreasing steps.
8. Double B.
9. Repeat from 7. with the next digit; if there are no more digits left, the numbers are equal.
10. If the number of steps is less than the best solution so far, choose this as the proposed solution.
11. Go back to step 2 for another selection.
12. After doing all selections from 2 we should have the optimal solution with the minimum number of steps.

The following examples are from an earlier version of the answer, where A is always the larger number and n=0, so we test only one selection.

*Example 17 and 65*

```
Power of 2: 2^2=4; 4x17=68
Difference: 68-65=3
3 = 010=10 in base 7/3/1

Start => 17/65
Decrease. Double. => 32/64
Double. => 64/64
```

*Example 18 and 67*

```
Power of 2: 2^2=4; 4x18=72
Difference: 72-67=5
5 = 012=12 in base 7/3/1

Start => 18/67
Decrease. Double. => 34/66
Decrease. Decrease. Double. => 64/64
```

*Example 10 and 137*

```
Power of 2: 2^4=16; 16*10=160
Difference: 160-137=23
23 = 1101 in base 15/7/3/1

Start => 10/137
Decrease. Double. => 18/136
Decrease. Double. => 34/135
Double. => 68/135
Decrease. Double. => 134/134
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a breadth-first search that does return the correct answer but may not be an optimal method of finding it. Maybe it can help others detect a pattern.
JavasScript code:

```js
function f(a, b) {
  const q = [[a, b, [a, b]]];
  
  while (true){
    const [x, y, path] = q.shift();
    if (x == y) {
      return path;
    }
    if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
      q.push([x-1, y-1, path.concat([x-1, y-1])]);
    }
    q.push([2*x, y, path.concat([2*x, y])]);
    q.push([x, 2*y, path.concat([x, 2*y])]);
  }
  
  return [];
}

function showPath(path) {
  let out1 = "";
  let out2 = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i += 2) {
    const s1 = path[i].toString(2);
    const s2 = path[i+1].toString(2);
    const len = Math.max(s1.length, s2.length);
    out1 += s1.padStart(len, "0");
    out2 += s2.padStart(len, "0");
    if (i < path.length - 2) {
      out1 += " --> ";
      out2 += " --> ";
    }
  }
  console.log(out1);
  console.log(out2);
}

showPath(f(89, 7));
```